# Cache-control in Tomcat

Tags: internet-explorer, http, tomcat, single-sign-on, cache-control

We have run into a problem with Internet Explorer where it is unable to handle the Cache-control header set to no-store for SSL downloads. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308 for more details.

Unfortunately when Tomcat authentication is enabled it appears to automatically add the Cache-control header with the value no-store.

I know that there is a workaround for when using the BasicAuthenticator in Tomcat. See http://daveharris.wordpress.com/2007/07/09/how-to-configure-cache-control-in-tomcat/. This solution describes using the disableProxyCaching attribute on the authenticator.

However, we are using SSO authentication using org.apache.catalina.ha.authenticator.ClusterSingleSignOn which does not appear to have the disableProxyCaching attribute. Is there a way to change the cache-control headers when using SSO?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Filter that will run over the cache-control header that tomcat imposes.

response.setHeader("cache-control", );
chain.doFilter(request, response);